# Rider - wrap long line

Tags: rider

I see that there is an option to break lines during writing code (Settings -> Code style -> Hard Wrap at), but I want rider to just visually break lines when displaying code with very long ones, without adding new spaces to code - just like VisualStudio setting Text Editor -> All languages -> General -> Word wrap.

Comment: Look for soft wrap.

Answer (score 30):

I found that I must specify what kind of files here in order to get wrap for every file or just * for all files If u like

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Toggle Soft wrap using <kbd>CTRL+E, W</kbd>

Double press the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to bring up the command search, type soft and the keyboard shortcut is displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's in *Preferences > Editor > General > Soft Wraps*.

[image: Soft Wraps]